# Может ли Spring или Selenium блокировать System.in?

Tags: java, spring, selenium

Есть код который должен получать текст с консоли, но он работает толкьо отдельно, а в контексте приложения не работает. Само приложение на Spring и использует селениум.

Может ли Spring млм Selenium блокировать `System.in`?

Все выполнение встает на `scanner.nextLine()` а консоль ввод не принимает.

Вот код :

```
@Autowired
private Browser chrome;

...

private void verify() {
    WebElement element = chrome.findElement(By.xpath("..."));
    if (isNull(element)) {
        return;
    }
    element.click();
    chrome.findElement(By.id("...")).sendKeys(getCode());
    chrome.findElement(By.xpath("...")).click();
}

private String getCode() {
    String result;
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)){
        result = scanner.nextLine();
        while (result.length() != 6 || !result.matches("[0-9]+")) {
            log.error("Enter valid 6-chars number code.");
            result = scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Все выполнение просто встает на

Comment: selenium точно нет. да и спринг тоже не должен. вы точно нигде не трогаете  `System.in`?  попробуйте еще getCode вызывть. сохранить в переменную и потом только передавать данные

Comment: не блокируют ни один, ни второй. у System.in есть методы close, reset. Попробуйте их вызвать перед вашим сканером. Или освободит ресурс, или упадет с исключение, во втором случае будет шанс вычислить по исключению.